# How should I pass a parameter from one XSLT template to another?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm having trouble passing a parameter to a template.

```
<!-- // Product / Instances -->
<xsl:template match="/data/products/instances">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item">
            <xsl:with-param name="idp" select="@id"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<!-- // Product / Instances / Instance -->
<xsl:template match="/data/products/instances/item">
    <xsl:param name="idp"/>
    <p>$idp: <xsl:value-of select="$idp"/></p> <!-- $idp is empty -->
    <xsl:for-each select="/data/instances/entry">
        <xsl:if test="@id = $idp">
            <p><xsl:value-of select="code"/></p>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

`/data/products/instances/item` has an attribute named `id`, which has a value of an integer.

Although the second template and its for-each loop are being processed (I've tested them by outputting dummy output from within them), the value of the `$idp` parameter is not being passed to the second template.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to show enough details to allow us to reproduce the issue, otherwise it is hard to tell what goes wrong.

I think you don't need any parameter, and you should use a key

```
<xsl:key name="k1" match="data/instances/entry" use="@id"/>

<!-- // Product / Instances -->
<xsl:template match="/data/products/instances">
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<!-- // Product / Instances / Instance -->
<xsl:template match="/data/products/instances/item">

    <xsl:for-each select="key('k1', @id)">

            <p><xsl:value-of select="code"/></p>

    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you do the apply-templates, your current context is on the **instances** element, and so the attribute **@id** refers to the attribute id of the **instances** element, and not the attribute on the **item** elements you are going to select (which have not yet been selected at that point).

In this sample given, there is no actually need to pass in a parameter. Simply use a variable in the matching template instead. Insteaf of the **xsl:param**, do the following:

```
<xsl:variable name="idp" select="@id"/>
```

This will get the value of the **id** attribute for you, as you are positioned on the **item** element at that point.

Comment: Thanks! The `xsl:variable` solution you gave works. Regarding the `xsl:with-param`, I found that even when doing `<xsl:with-param name="idp" select="'73'"/>`, I couldn't get the integer output in the second template. I'd also tried `item/@id`, thinking the context might be the issue.